# Generating href with a function

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to write a custom WordPress theme.

I put this in my `header.php`:

```
  <h1>Roux Academy of Art and Design
        <a href="<?php echo siteRoot('Blog'); ?>index.htm" title="home"></a>
    </h1>
```

I'd like the the link inside the `h1` to point to `index.html`, but when I add the PHP bit inside my `href` everything disappears and I get a blank page.

I have this in my `functions.php`:

```
<?php
    function siteRoot($theFolder) {
        $home = get_home_url();
        // strpos(string, substring)
        $thePosition = strpos($home,$theFolder);
        // substr (string, start, length)
        $thePath = substr($home, 0, $thePosition);
        return $thePath;
    }
?>
```

What could the problem be?

i try this code in header.php but still not working

```
<h1>Roux Academy of Art and Design<a href="
<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '../../../Blog/roux_academy/index.html' ) ); ?>
```

Comment: I assume you mean `functions.php`. From the looks of it, you're using substr wrong in an attempt to get the wordpress instation directory. You don't even need to define a `siteRoot()` function. Try using, instead, `home_url()`. Which can be found in the manual here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/home_url

Comment: As @Ultimater suggests, use the wordpress built-in function `home_url()`. That function already handles all the stuff creating the link to your index page.

Comment: ok great i want it to go to that link     <h1>Roux Academy of Art and Design<a href="
<?php echo esc_url( home_url( 'C:\xampp\htdocs\courses\Blog\roux_academy\index.html' ) ); ?> which i am in the the theme folder in web content

Comment: i try this but not work    <h1>Roux Academy of Art and Design<a href="
<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '../../../Blog/roux_academy/index.html' ) ); ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not this way?

```
<h1>Roux Academy of Art and Design
    <a href="<?php home_url(); ?>/index.htm" title="home"></a>
</h1>
```

Comment: ok great i want it to go to that link <h1>Roux Academy of Art and Design<a href=" <?php echo esc_url( home_url( 'C:\xampp\htdocs\courses\Blog\roux_academy\index.html' ) ); ?> which i am in the the theme folder in web content

Comment: i try this but not work      <h1>Roux Academy of Art and Design<a href="
<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '../../../Blog/roux_academy/index.html' ) ); ?>

Answer (score 0):

use home_url() or in this case you can only do this without any php code  :

```
 <h1>Roux Academy of Art and Design
        <a href="/index.htm" title="home"></a>
    </h1
```

Answer (score 0):

its work when i add the path of the page like that

```
<h1>Roux Academy of Art and Design<a href="
<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/Blog/roux_academy/' ) ); ?>
index.html" title="home"></a></h1>
```